# How to replace jQuery Event name with variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to replace jQuery event name with variable like the following?
If there is, how? If not, why?

Thank you very much.
The original code:

```
var menu = $('.menu');
var search_bar = $('#search_bar');
var bar = $('#bar');
var icon = $('.myicon');

search_bar.focusin(function(){
    search_bar.css('width','20%');
    menu.css('width','80%');
    bar.css('color', '#000);
    icon.css('color', '#000);
});
```

The code I'd like to have:

```
function doSomething(tag, tagAction, actionAttributes) {
    if ((tag) && (tagAction)) {
        $(tag).???tagAction(actionAttributes.key, actionAttributes.val);
    }
}
```

???tagAction stands for 'css', is there a wildcard symbol that can replace event name, or I should have to use 'switch' to let the code below work correctly?

```
doSomething(".menu", "css", "{'width':'80%'}");
```

Comment: I'd recommend using `addClass` and moving all the CSS to a class within your CSS file. Then you can `addClass` when the user focuses on the search bar.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string

Comment: I don't like `var menu = $('.menu');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation)

```
function doSomething(tag, tagAction, actionAttributes) {
    if ((tag) && (tagAction)) {
        $(tag)[tagAction](actionAttributes.key, actionAttributes.val);
    }
}
```

Notice, the way you are trying to call `doSomething` won't work, as the `actionAttributes` variable is a string, not an object. Calling it like this will work.

```
doSomething(".menu", "css", {key:'width', val:'80%'});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try it now! How to deal with .? No need for it? $(tag).[tagAction](...)?

Comment: Yeah, no need for it. You can just use `[]`